# Word for the thing that moves back and forth in a watch mechanism

Tags: single-word-requests

The reason I'm asking is because it is a singular word in Swedish "oro". It is a fitting technical term that translates roughly to "concern, fidgeting".

I find it curious English not having a singular word for this.

I have found "balance wheel", "watch movement" I suppose *watch* is redundant in context.
I've also seen "watch calibre", same caveat.

Is calibre the word I'm looking for?

As a reaction to the helpful answer by Ricky. I'd like to find a word that is not as ambiguous or context dependent. I don't mind an exotic word.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your question, but maybe the word you are asking for is pendulous, the movement from a pendulum?

Comment: @ClickOk a pendulum occurs in a pendulum clock.  The watch equivalent is a [balance wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balance_wheel)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe that would be the [escapement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escapement).

Here’s a description:

> The escapement is a mechanism that translates rotational energy into
> lateral impulses. The tick-tock sound you hear when holding a watch to
> your ear is from the escapement. The pallet fork locks and unlocks
> with the escape wheel at each vibration of the balance wheel.
> <sub>Source: [Hodinkee — *Watch
> 101*](https://www.hodinkee.com/watch101/escapement)</sub>

In real life, though, few people would have any idea of what you’re talking about.

I submit to you instead a mashup that employs a few productive English language tactics:

- **onomatopoeia** ([the process of creating a word that phonetically
  imitates, resembles, or suggests the sound that it
  describes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onomatopoeia))
- **metonomy** ([a figure of speech in which a thing or concept is referred
  to by the name of something closely associated with that thing or concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy))
- **[derivational suffixing](https://lexsrv2.nlm.nih.gov/LexSysGroup/Projects/lvg/2015/docs/designDoc/UDF/derivations/suffixList.html)
  with *-er*** (turning a verb into noun that is person or thing that does the verb).

So, here you go . . .

> ***tick-tocker***

Here’s an example usage:

> *I can’t hear anything; the tick-tocker must be broken.*

Proceed at your own risk.

Comment: Personally, I'd go with "ticker". Full-size clocks tick-tock, watches merely tick.

Comment: The escapement and the balance wheel are two different things.  The balance wheel is the spring+disk that provides the rotational energy, the escapement is the pair of branched "hooks"  that keep the watch mechanism moving at the same step-speed.  See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balance_wheel#History  In some sense, both of them "move back and forth".

Comment: @NoName: at least in en_US 'ticker' is not used for watches, or clocks either. It is used for the heart (which I would consider slang), and was used for [pre-computer devices used to transmit stock/security market prices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ticker_tape), so that most people in the investment/financial industry today continue to use it figuratively for any feed or display of financial market prices.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: I would say that — while both move back and forth — the balance wheel rocks and the escapement fidgets. [How a Mechanical Watch Works](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9_QsCLYs2mY)

Answer (score 7):

Just *balance* will do.

**balance**

15. Also called balance wheel. Horology. a wheel that oscillates against the tension of a hairspring to regulate the beats of a watch or clock.

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/balance

Comment: Thanks Ricky. Apparently this falls under 

    Edit wars
    Extended bickering in comments (but see: a guide to moderating comments)
    A controversial post that is under discussion on meta

Answer (score 6):

The **escapement**, as defined by [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/escapement) is:

> a device in a timepiece which controls the motion of the train of
> wheelwork and through which the energy of the power source is
> delivered to the pendulum or balance by means of impulses that permit
> a tooth to escape from a pallet at regular intervals

See also *How a Mechanical Watch Works* on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9_QsCLYs2mY)

Answer (score 0):

While that part is called *[oro](https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oro_(urdetalj))* in Swedish, it's *[onrust](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onrust_(uurwerk))* in Dutch and *[unruh](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unruh_(Uhr))* in German. A naïve translation for both would be *unrest*, but not in the sense of civil unrest, but rather *uncalm* and indeed *fidgeting*.

Going by Wikipedia, the correct English name of that part is indeed *[balance wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balance_wheel)*, which doesn't have those same connotations. Note that the name for this part seems to be similar in [French](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balancier_(horlogerie)), [Italian](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilanciere_(orologeria)), and [Polish](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balans).

Answer (score -1):

> *I find it curious English not having a singular word for this.*

We have a few.  It depends on precisely what you wish to describe.

The pure back-and-forth movement, especially whithin limits:

**Oscillate**

> OED:
> verb [ no obj. ]
> move or swing back and forth in a regular rhythm: the grain pan near the front of the combine oscillates back and forth.
> • [ with adverbial ] vary or fluctuate between two states, limits, opinions, etc.: he was oscillating between fear and bravery.

Whereas *oscillate* pertains to the back-and-forth movement of the thing, *escapement* pertains to the delivery of power (the power of the spring *escapes* into the cogs that move the hands).

> *I'd like to find a word that is not as ambiguous*

Yes, that is to be avoided.

> *or context dependent*

No.  All Indo-European languages (including Swedish) are context-dependent, it is a principle, you can't get away from it.  The sense of the word is modulated by the context that it is used in.  Refer to the examples in the OED definition:

- the balance wheel oscillates between clockwise and anti-clockwise,
- the claw oscillates between capture and escape,
- the person oscillated between fear and bravery.